# Alertmanager docker container refuses connections

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a docker-compose file with one django app, Prometheus monitoring container and Alertmanager container.

All builds fine, app is running, Prometheus is monitoring but when it is to fire an alert, the alert does not reach the Alertmanager container with the following error message:

```
prometheus_1    | level=error ts=2021-08-02T08:58:16.018Z caller=notifier.go:527 component=notifier alertmanager=http://0.0.0.0:9093/api/v2/alerts count=1 msg="Error sending alert" err="Post \"http://0.0.0.0:9093/api/v2/alerts\": dial tc
p 0.0.0.0:9093: connect: connection refused"
```

Alertmanager also refuses telnet test connection like so

```
klex@DESKTOP-PVC5EP:~$ telnet 0.0.0.0 9093
Trying 0.0.0.0...
Connected to 0.0.0.0.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

the docker-compose file is:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    container_name: smsgate
    build: .
    command: sh -c "python manage.py migrate &&
      python manage.py collectstatic --no-input && 
      python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:15001"
    volumes:
      - .:/smsgate:rw
      - static_volume:/home/app/smsgate/static
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - "15001:15001"
    env_file:
      - .env.prod
    image: smsgate
    restart: "always"
    networks:
      - promnet

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    volumes:
    - ./prometheus/:/etc/prometheus/
    depends_on:
      - alertmanager
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    networks:
      - promnet

  alertmanager:
    image: prom/alertmanager
    ports:
      - "9093:9093"
    volumes:
      - ./alertmanager/:/etc/alertmanager/
    restart: "always"
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml'
    networks:
      - promnet

volumes:
  static_volume:
  alertmanager_volume:
  prometheus_volume:

networks:
  promnet:
    driver: bridge
```

And prometheus.yml configuration file is

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
        - targets:
            - "0.0.0.0:9093"
rule_files:
  - alert.rules.yml

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: monitoring
    metrics_path: /metrics
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - smsgate:15001
```

There is very likely a network? configuration problem either as the service seems not to accept any connections.

Prometheus and Alertmanager GUI interfaces can be accessed via browser on
`http://127.0.0.1:9090/` and
`http://127.0.0.1:9093/` respectively

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the **service name** instead of the `0.0.0.0`. Change the last line in the configuration of alerting block as:

```
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
        - targets:
            - "alertmanager:9093"
```

given that they are on the same net, it should work just fin

## Update

I misunderstood the problem in the first place. Apologies. Please check the updated block above ☝

Comment: Tried with no success. This block is about App>Prometheus communication which works fine.

Comment: Apologies David, I missed the point here. I have edited my answer, hopefully, now it is better 